# Changing Imageview on click of ListViewItem in android

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, imageview

I have a listview and what I want is when I click on listView row, the Imageview which I have used in ListView row changes to different drawable. Here is the code what I have tried.

```
lvAdminData.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    View convertView, int position, long id) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                RelativeLayout rel=(RelativeLayout) adapter.getView(position, null,null);
                ImageView arrowView=(ImageView) rel.getChildAt(2);
                arrowView.setImageResource(R.drawable.info_details_navigation_white);
                            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the snapshot:

[image: This white should turn into blue on click of row]

Comment: what is the problem exactly?

Comment: I want that anywhere on this row I click and this arrow image change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
lvAdminData.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View convertView, int position, long id)  {    

        ImageView arrowView=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.yourid);  //replace with your ImageView id
        arrowView.setImageResource(R.drawable.info_details_navigation_white);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in

```
lvAdminData.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View convertView, int position, long id)  {    

    ImageView arrowView=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageid);  
    arrowView.setImageResource(R.drawable.info_details_navigation_white);
    }
```

});

Comment: Your code will work when we will click on Image but I want wherever One click on row , It should change.

Comment: try with convertView.setOnClickListner and see

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rel.invalidate() ;
```

after

```
arrowView.setImageResource(R.drawable.info_details_navigation_white);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I have directly found id of imageview . Now its working.

```
lvAdminData
        .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    View convertView, int position, long id) {

                ImageView arrowView=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewArrow);
                arrowView.setImageResource(R.drawable.info_details_navigation);
                onAdminItemClick(parent, position);
            }
        });
```

Comment: try using more items, so that you have to scroll and see if it still works, when you scroll up and down.